# Collect data using simout for an experiment with thousands of runs

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm using this code (shown below) to run a Simulink model for thousands of runs. I want for each run to collect all the results. 
Is there a way to collect the result each run and then organize them?

I did try simout, but I got a result for just one run.

```
Run(1).Settings={'....'};
Run(2).Setting={'....'};
....

dirout=sprintf('......,clock);
mkdir(dirout);
numofruns=length(Run); % or I can set it to 10000

for i=1:numofruns
counter=counter+1;
disp(['Run:'num2str(Counter) '/' num2str(numofruns)])
for j=1:size(Run(i).Settings,1)
set_param([modelname '/' Run(i).Settings{j,1} '/enabled/' 
Run(i).Settings{j,2}],'value', num2str(Run(i).Settings{j,3}));
end 
set_param(modelname,'StopTime',num2str(StopTime));
sim(modelname);
filename=sprintf('%s/simout_%05.0f.mat',dirout,i);
simout=simout';
save(filename,'simout');
end
```

The collected results should show the outcomes of every single run. 
For example:

simout of run 1

simout of run 2
and so on

Your help is highly appreciated

Comment: How big is the result data - can you accumulate it in a cell array for example, or will that not fit in memory? What do you want to do with the 'collected results' - plot them together on a graph, calculate statistics, calculate differences, ?

Comment: Thanks, @nekomatic. For each run, I have two columns with 1000 rows. I'm not sure if it will fit in memory. I want to plot them together on a graph and calculate statistics and differences.

Comment: If you are using a modern version of Simulink, the Simulink Data Inspector will allow you to capture and compare data across multiple runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 1000 x 2 array of double-precision floating-point numbers only takes up 16000 bytes:

```
>> myMatrix = rand(1000, 2);
>> whos('myMatrix')
  Name             Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  myMatrix      1000x2             16000  double
```

so you should be able to fit tens of thousands of them in memory without trouble. If your simulation output will always be the same size, you can store them in a 3-dimensional array:

```
% preallocate the array to prevent memory reallocation, which is slow
resultArray = zeros(numofruns, 1000, 2);

for i = 1:numofruns
    % run the simulation here, assume it returns 1000 x 2 matrix simout

    resultArray(i,:,:) = simout;
end
```

If the number of rows may vary from one run to the next, you can use a cell array:

```
resultCellArray = cell(numofruns);

for i = 1:numofruns
    % run simulation here

    resultCellArray{i} = simout;
end
```

If you really are generating too much data to fit in memory at once, but you want to store it in one file and be able to access arbitrary subsets of it for analysis, you probably want to look at the techniques for working with [large MAT-files](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/large-mat-files.html). This will be much, much slower than handling data in memory.

Alternatively, you could try using the [Simulation Data Inspector](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/simulationdatainspector.html), although I don't know whether that can handle data too large for memory.